# Why can't I see more than the first product SKU in facebook business manager?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel, data-layers

I'm trying to set up a facebook purchase event in GTM and i'm almost there but i son't understand why I can only see the first product from the transactiuon array in facebook business manager? I can see that a transaction been made and I can see the value but only one product SKU!

This is the datalayer after a specifik purchase, with two different kind of tickets:

```
{
    transactionId: "31000226",
    transactionTotal: 243,
    transactionProducts: [
        {
            name: "Adult",
            sku: "Adult",
            price: 135,
            quantity: 1,
            category: "tickets"
        },
        {
            name: "Pensioner",
            sku: "Pensioner",
            price: 108,
            quantity: 1,
            category: "tickets"
        }
    ],
```

And this is my GTM-tag for the facebook purchase event:

```
<script>
  fbq('track', 'Purchase',{
    products: '[{{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}}]',
    value: '{{DLV - Ecommerce - TransactionTotal}}',   
    currency: 'SEK'
  });
</script>
```

The datalayer variable {{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}} is set up like this in GTM:

> ***transactionProducts.0.sku***

This is what I can see in facebook business manager:

> Parametrar: (3)
>
> value: 243
>
> currency: SEK
>
> products: [Adult]

Does anyone see the problem? Why can't I in this exampel see the second ticket that says "*Pensioner*"?

Comment: that would be `transactionProducts.1.sku`

Comment: Okey, but I want products in the facebook-event to populate it self. so if someone buys 1 item you see 1 item (SKU) and someone buys 4 items you see 4 items (SKUs)

Comment: Or even more preferably Prduct SKU and quantity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom variable “sku variable” for the sku to be the below:

```
function () {
{{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}}.forEach {
return sku
};
}
```

Change the  {{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}} to just transactionProducts

Comment: thanks! should I have    products: '[{{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}}]' in the pixel-event or should it be    products: '[{{New SKU varible CJ}}]'?

Comment: It should be products: ‘{New SKU variable CJ}} as that variable should return an array so no need to add the array [] around the variable.

Comment: when I try it ut in the console I get an error about the { after forEach. Why is that? This is what i says in the error messeage: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'"

Comment: Sorry forgot a } try - function () {
{{DLV - Ecommerce - Product}}.forEach {
return sku
}}